How to change the value of MAXFILHANDLES
I'm working with a Delphi app on windows 11, when i want to change the value of MAXFILHANDLES using:
BDE Administrator: Configuration->System->INIT->MAXFILHANDLES

The stuff doesn't work for me.
Note: the BDE installed is 32bit, I can't find the 64 bit on the net. I tried to look for a 64 bit version for the BDE to test if it will work, but didn't manage to find any version.

BDE is deprecated for far over 10 years now, so there is probably no x64 version available!

Try to run the BDE Administrator utility as administrator.

thanks a lot Zhorov
that worked

BDE stopped being relevant about 20 years ago, it's just amazing that it lives on

As others have said, the BDE has been deprecated for more than a decade now, which means it has stopped being updated. There is no 64-bit version, and never will be. You've had 10+ years to convert your app to use something else instead, and should have used it. At some point, due to OS changes, it's going to just stop working, and you're going to just be stuck with an app that doesn't function at all.
